# Is it necessary to reinforce a carbon fiber steer tube?

Tags: carbon, mechanical

There seems to a belief circulating online that carbon fiber steer tubes need to be reinforced with the compression plug specifically underneath the clamp points of the stem.  If this is true, why isn't it necessary to reinforce (with a compression plug or in some other manner) carbon fiber seatposts and handlebars, both of which are tubular and generally subject to greater stresses than a steer tube?

Comment: Good question, especially given that the fork steerer designer can't be sure that the compression plug will be fitted in the 'correct' place, and they can be quite small compared to the stem clamp. It would be diligent to make the steerer strong enough to clamp around by itself. I look forward to the answer

Comment: CFC steerers *are* strong enough to be clamped by the stem, as long as the torque specs for the clamp bolts are adhered to.

Comment: I suspect that seat posts and handle bars are laid up with fibers perpendicular to the post (circles). As its easy to install compression plug into a stem, some manufacturers will choose to save weight (in the fork, so the all important glossy looks good)  and money buy designing for a compression plug. Others may put in circular fibres so not need compression plugs.  Not an answer as I cannot back this up.

Comment: Not compression plug, but there is at least one fork for which the manufacturer recommends glued aluminum insert: https://www.derby-cycle.com/fileadmin/Downloads/Antriebe/Allgemein/Cervelo/12_2007_Cervelo_3T20_fork_instruction_EN.pdf

Comment: In comparison to seatpost or handlebars, broken steerer tube means instant loss of control and balance. This is much worse than broken seatpost and even if handlebar breaks, you'll probably lose only one side.

Comment: I recall that the main purpose of a compression plug in carbon steerers is to provide an anchor for the top cap bolt. You need to pull the stem down very slightly to make sure it seats firmly on the top of the headset (i.e. to preload the headset). Two people make that point in the discussion linked later. Reinforcing the steerer from within may be a secondary function, but I have no idea if this is true. https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/516424-what-purpose-compression-plug.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing about requiring a compression plug inside the carbon fiber steerer in [Trek's owner's manual](http://bike-manual.com/brands/trek/om/road/fork.htm).

Given the plethora of warnings embedded [throughout that document](http://bike-manual.com/brands/trek/om/road/index.htm), I'd say such a lack is definitive.  So, despite it being impossible to prove a negative, umm. no:

In general*, carbon fiber steer tubes do not **need** to be reinforced with a compression plug.

[The myriad of compression plugs available](https://www.google.com/search?q=steerer+tube+compression+plug&tbm=isch) support this assertion.  There are plugs that cover the entire inside of the tube from just a few mm under the cap down well past the stem.  There are plugs that reach down only a few mm total.  There are plugs that "hang" down inside the steer tube several cm from the cap before a short plug grabs the steer tube for a cm or so.  If the plugs were in general needed to support the steer tube, they'd **all** be longer than the 3 cm or so length that stem clamps onto the steer tube.  **And** user manuals would have warnings not to put too many spacers on the top of the stem that would prevent the compression plug from being located properly.  The Trek user manual linked above has no such warnings.  It only states that there must be *at least* one 5 mm spacer above the stem.

* - because there's going to be one out there somewhere that does say it's needed...